# java reflection field bitwise operation

Tags: java, reflection, bit-manipulation

I do have good understanding of bitwise operations. My question is case-specific. In the following code taken from oracle tutorial, is it possible to change the expression:

```
if ((foundMods & searchMods) == searchMods)
```

To:

```
if (foundMods == searchMods)
```

? ... because we are not extracting any flag, we are only testing for equality. Right? ... or am I missing something?

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import static java.lang.System.out;

enum Spy { BLACK , WHITE }

public class FieldModifierSpy {
volatile int share;
int instance;
class Inner {}

public static void main(String... args) {
try {
    Class<?> c = Class.forName(args[0]);
    int searchMods = 0x0;
    for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
    searchMods |= modifierFromString(args[i]);
    }

    Field[] flds = c.getDeclaredFields();
    out.format("Fields in Class '%s' containing modifiers:  %s%n",
           c.getName(),
           Modifier.toString(searchMods));
    boolean found = false;
    for (Field f : flds) {
    int foundMods = f.getModifiers();
    // Require all of the requested modifiers to be present
    if ((foundMods & searchMods) == searchMods) {
        out.format("%-8s [ synthetic=%-5b enum_constant=%-5b ]%n",
               f.getName(), f.isSynthetic(),
               f.isEnumConstant());
        found = true;
    }
    }

    if (!found) {
    out.format("No matching fields%n");
    }

    // production code should handle this exception more gracefully
} catch (ClassNotFoundException x) {
    x.printStackTrace();
}
}

private static int modifierFromString(String s) {
int m = 0x0;
if ("public".equals(s))           m |= Modifier.PUBLIC;
else if ("protected".equals(s))   m |= Modifier.PROTECTED;
else if ("private".equals(s))     m |= Modifier.PRIVATE;
else if ("static".equals(s))      m |= Modifier.STATIC;
else if ("final".equals(s))       m |= Modifier.FINAL;
else if ("transient".equals(s))   m |= Modifier.TRANSIENT;
else if ("volatile".equals(s))    m |= Modifier.VOLATILE;
return m;
}
}
```

Comment: It is possible, but will change the behavior...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
if ((foundMods & searchMods) == searchMods)
```

says "if `foundMods` includes all the bits in `searchMods`".

This:

```
if (foundMods == searchMods)
```

would be "if `foundMods` has all the same bits as `searchMods` (and no others)".

If you *know* that `foundMods` won't have any other bits, then they're equivalent. Otherwise they are definitely different.

Comment: Thanks. Good quick concise answer. Keep up helping beginners.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer** No

**More answer**
Your assumption,
that `if ((foundMods & searchMods) == searchMods)` is equivalent to
`if (foundMods == searchMods)` is not valid.

The first if tests to see if all one value bits in the `searchMods` value are also one value bits in the `foundMods` value.

Thus,
if `searchMods == 0000111` and `foundMods == 0011111` then
`if ((foundMods & searchMods) == searchMods)` is true, but `if (foundMods == searchMods)` is false.

In the case of field modifiers,
searchMods may be a subset of modifiers that are present for the current (foundMods) field.

Answer (score 0):

Let foundMods be Modifier.PUBLIC | Modifier.STATIC | Modifier.FINAL
Now let searchMods be Modifier.PUBLIC.
`foundMods & searchMods) == searchMods` will evaluate to `true`, whereas
`foundMods == searchMods` will be `false`.
So, yes, you're missing something and no, you cannot replace the first by the latter expression.

Answer (score 0):

> we are not extracting any flag, we are only testing for equality. Right?

No. `searchMods` is a collection of all the "lit" flags you want to search for. Using the `&` operator like that will check if `foundMods` has all the "lit" flags that `searchMods` has - but it will ignore additional flags that `foundMods` may have, while the `==` operator will not.

Consider the following example:

```
int searchMods = Modifier.PUBLIC | Modifier.STATIC;
int foundMods = Modifier.PUBLIC | Modifier.STATIC | Modifier.SYNCHRONIZED;

System.out.println((foundMods & searchMods) == searchMods);
System.out.println(foundMods == searchMods);
```

The first print statement will print `true`, while the second will print `false`.